# RoR, Devise: Route to sign in redirects to users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When I go to localhost:3000/users/sign_in, I am redirected to users#show with an error (as there is no current user) instead of the sign in page. By everything I can figure, this should not be happening, yet it is. I am redirected both if I click a link to new_user_session_path, or if I type the URI directly.

I have looked through my routes for duplicates and I have cleared the session and cache. Honestly the whole Devise interface is so simple, I'm not sure what else to check. And this worked earlier, so clearly something has changed.

What else could be going wrong?

**Rake Routes**

```
# output from rake:routes
# there are no other routes for this GET path

new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
```

**Routes.rb**

```
#config/routes.rb

resources :users
devise_for :users
```

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/user_controller.rb

before_action :confirm_signed_in

def confirm_signed_in
  unless user_signed_in?
    initiate_return_to_last_successful
    flash.now[:notice] = 'Please sign in.'
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Note: I most recently was trying to modify the Devise registrations controller create action. I'm not sure if that caused it, but I've backed out of all changes associated with it (I believe. Checked three times.)

Comment: Devise does have a before_action, `authenticate_user!` that can replace your `confirm_signed_in`. [Check the docs here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Comment: Thanks. Since I wanted to modify it, I just made my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch these two lines. Routes at the top of the file take precedence, and so the issue is resources for uses route pattern-matching.

This route, generated by the `resources` method, matches **any route in the format of** `/users/anything_can_go_here`, and the part that replaces `:id` will be available in the controller as `params[:id]`.

```
GET '/users/:id' => 'users#show'
```

This route, generated by devise, needs to be placed **above the call to `resources :users`**, for it to have precedence in the eyes of Rails.

```
GET 'users/sign_in' => 'users#sign_in'
```

To fix this problem, this

```
resources :users
devise_for :users
```

Should be

```
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

To learn more about routing in Ruby on Rails, check out [this guide/tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: That was it, and that explains it. Thank you!